# Kivy button from one screen access another screen does not work

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, methods, kivy

I am throughly confused on Kivy OOP concept despite some help from a few members from previous posts and reading on different examples.

The code snippet is as short as I can cut it down to.

My question is how do I access the method from Screen_2 to Screen_1.  If I understand python and OOP correctly, the way is written is correct.  You add an instance of the class and then use that instance to access the method, however it's not working.   the following is updated code after my final comments:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    main_screen = ObjectProperty()
    profile_screen = ObjectProperty()

class MainScreen(Screen):
    first_name_text_input= ObjectProperty()
    last_name_text_input= ObjectProperty()
    student_list = ObjectProperty()

    def submit_student(self):
        print ("hi")

class ProfileScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.app = App.get_running_app()
        self.a = self.app.ms

    def okay(self):
        self.a.submit_student()


class StudentDBApp(App):
    ms = MainScreen()

    def build(self):
        return Manager()

if __name__=="__main__":
    StudentDBApp().run()
```

Generally I understand how OOP works.  My struggle is always comes down to GUIs and OOP.  thanks again for your time.

here is the kv file

```
<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager
    main_screen: main_screen
    profile_screen: profile_screen

    MainScreen:
        id: main_screen
        name:"main_screen"
        manager: screen_manager

    ProfileScreen:
        id: profile_screen
        name: "profile_screen"
        manager: screen_manager

<MainScreen>:
    first_name_text_input: first_name
    last_name_text_input: last_name
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text:"First Name:"
            TextInput:
                id: first_name
            Label:
                text:"Last Name:"
            TextInput:
                id: last_name
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text:"Submit"
                on_release: root.submit_student()

            Button:
                text: "New"
                on_release: root.manager.current="profile_screen"


<ProfileScreen>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text:"Back"
                on_release: root.manager.current="main_screen"

            Button:
                text: "Okay"
                on_release: root.okay()
```

Comment: Is there a `kv` file that goes with this code? Your build method is building a `Screen_Manager` with no `Screens`.

Comment: hi @John Anderson.  I add it in now.  I probably didn't tell you this is my first Kivy project.  I wrote the first version in tkinter, and it works.  I want to do it in Kivy to put it on mobile.  I already able to put the program on android, only the program itself is not finished.  thanks again for the pointers.

Comment: If the problem is with `root.wifi_info()`, it is because you have not defined that method at all.

Comment: hi @John Anderson,  It's included now.  I was trying to cut down to bare min and did's included it.  the design of the app supposed to allow the user to enter their own wifi info on screen 2.  then on screen 1, i will create a socket to connect to the network.  Since the method is there, I just need to access it. that is where my problem lies.  thanks again.

Comment: hi @John Anderson, I figured out to some extend how to connect a function from a different class to be used in a given class.  I updated the code.  This is not what I want, but at least the above code works to show calling a function from a different class.  .  I will post another question in the future when I run into trouble.  thanks again.